# Merge Images With Node

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm using Node.js GM and trying to merge an image onto another at a certain x, y point. How can I achieve this with GraphicsMagick? Is it possible to use append and specify coordinates instead of left-to-right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `composite` method see docs from GM

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/composite.html

`append` is normally handy for creating sprites

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm very new to GM and I couldn't find one on the page. Thanks. I'm trying to emulate imagecopymerge() from GD.

Comment: I'm sorry, I lead you on a wild goose chase... You want `composite` instead... I updated the link and there are samples there